# How do I change the $\xi$ symbol in mathpazo

Tags: symbols

I don't like the `$\xi$` symbol that `mathpazo` comes with, so I want to go back to Computer Modern for that symbol alone. How can I do this?

Comment: You should follow the instructions listed in [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/5764).

Comment: I looked at that question, but I'm not sure how to find what number the `\xi` symbol is in the `letters` symbols

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code is in `fontmath.ltx`:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xi}{\mathord}{letters}{"18}
```

To make the change you want, you can fetch the CM definition of `letters` and change it into

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{CMletters}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}
```

and then

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xi}{\mathord}{CMletters}{"18}
```

Comment: when i use `\DeclareSymbolFont{CMlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}‎‎‎
\DeclareMathSymbol{\‎‏‎sum‎}{\mathop}{CMlargesymbols}{"50}‎‎‎`, it results an error: "Command '\sum' already defined". how can i change the `sum` symbol?

Comment: @smh I don't get this error; please, open a new question, with a link to this one, adding a minimal example producing the error.