# Change \pi symbol

Tags: symbols

I want to get this pi symbol

[image]

Because I don't like the original

[image]

Comment: You could something similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75475/128553.

Comment: Use `\boldsymbol{\pi}`.